# How to easily diff two nmap scan outputs?

Tags: nmap

I ran a scan, plugged in a raspberry pi, then ran a scan again.  Is there a utility or option within `nmap` that can allow me to easily diff the two scan outputs to find the IP address of my raspberry pi?

nmap scan used:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.86.1/24
```

It looks like `ndiff` can't be installed at the same time as `nmap` on mac:

```
$ brew install ndiff 
Error: Cannot install ndiff because conflicting formulae are installed.
  nmap: because both install `ndiff` binaries

Please `brew unlink nmap` before continuing.

Unlinking removes a formula's symlinks from /usr/local. You can
link the formula again after the install finishes. You can --force this
install, but the build may fail or cause obscure side effects in the
resulting software.
```

[Periodic Diffs](https://nmap.org/book/ndiff-man-periodic.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ndiff` ought to come with Nmap. Check if it's in your path already. If not, you can get it from the Nmap source tree, since it's just a single Python 2 script.

Comment: Ah, found it at: `/usr/local/bin/ndiff`